# Where do I add listeners when using Node.js with Loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, listener, loopbackjs

I am relatively new to Node.js and wanted to build a listener into the platform I am creating. I am using Loopback as the framework for all of this.

My first thought is to put it in the server.js, but I am not sure if that is best practice. Any code samples or links to tutorials that focus on eventing and listening to events would be very helpful. The primary focus for me is to figure out where things should go in the Node.js structure. I have tried researching online, however, I am met mostly with code snippets for just creating the function for the listener themselves, but not where they should really go in the code base.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first stop should probably to be the on-line examples and documentation: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Tutorials-and-examples.html.  Post back specific questions after you've tried some stuff on your own.

Comment: Best place to put them, is in your loopback project's /server/boot/ directory.

Comment: @tashakori Thanks. Appreciate the help